# Error: The requested URL “[no URL]”, is invalid

Tags: html, url, akamai

Originally posted as a reply to: [Error: The requested URL "[no URL]", is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39690489/error-the-requested-url-no-url-is-invalid)

I get this error but only with one specific website (which is my own). This must be linked to the website as it is happening on 3 different machines on 3 different networks (personal comp on personal wifi, phone on 4/3g and work pc on work network) and no other sites. Also, it happens no matter what you put after the domain name, weather its a real page or just '/sdjhlgajhsdfg'.

A reply to the other post said that it looks like somthing to do with akamai. As this is my site, i went to the CPanel and disabled the akamai options (over 24 hours ago). i do not need any kind of caching like this as it is a simple html css site with only a hand full of mostly text pages. The most complicated thing on the site is a downloadable pdf which i have actually just taken down.

The error ref number changes every time you refresh the page.

Reference #9.d7c33b8.1478565760.55ccef1

Reference #9.d7c33b8.1478566986.560a7c3

Reference #9.d7c33b8.1478567000.560b460

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Bump: Please can anyone give me some advice, its been at least 3 days (possibly longer without knowing) of  my website not being active. why vote me down when I have a genuine problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found some time to contact my webserver provider.

> I can see that the domain has been removed from the Akamai server.
>   However, the CNAME which was pointing to Akamai server was causing the
>   issue. I have removed the CNAME record.

after about half an hour its back up. theres some display issues with the layout, but at lease its displaying the relevant content and not the error.

Comment: Thank you!  I had pushed a virgin version directly to Akamai 'Production' environment, forgetting that there is none in Akamai 'Staging' environment. (Anup gets up and grabs a coffee)

Answer (score 4):

When you see Invalid URL error, this indicates that the hostname (domain) is not recognized by the Akamai's network (production or staging).

More info at: https://control.akamai.com/search/kb/11327

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a reverse proxy in before akamai you may get this error.

Client > Reverse Proxy > Akamai > Your API, will give this error.

Let your reverse proxy strip "Host" header and sent by "Client" and try again.
That worked for me in a setup like this:

Browser > Caddy Server > Akamai > My API

Answer (score 0):

in akamai i had to add a new property manager entry for the new url/cert then activate it in prod.